# Android Studio Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting the following error:

```
Error:(4, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
Possible causes:The project 'Jp' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file.The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
```

I tried looking to other similar questions, but nothing worked. 
My build.gradle(Project:JP) file is below:
**Error:(4, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jal.jp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(":sdk-audio-1.60.1")

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

build.gradle(sdk-audio-1.60.1)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jal.jp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(":sdk-audio-1.60.1")

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

settings.gradle:

```
include ':app', ':sdk-audio-1.60.1'
```

can anyone help me to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your build gradle tools seem too old, change the following line in the root build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

And don't forget to add google maven to your build.gradle too:

```
maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
```

This is because all support library are moved to maven as in the release note at https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html:

> Important: The support libraries are now available through Google's
>   Maven repository. You do not need to download the support repository
>   from the SDK Manager. For more information, see Support Library Setup.

So then your root build.gradle will be something like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Error:(1, 0) Minimum supported Gradle version is 3.3. Current version is 2.8. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\Jal\Jp\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-3.3-all.zip
I did as u mentioned but I got this error . can you please help?

Comment: It means that you should upgrade the gradle. try changing the line in **C:\Users\Jal\Jp\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties** to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip` in

Comment: I did that..its taking forever to build..thanks a lot though..appreciate it.

Comment: Error:(4, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments [project ':app'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.                                                                                                                       Following is the file:                                                                                                                     configurations.create("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('sdk-audio-1.60.1.aar'))
dependencies {
    compile project(':app')
    
}

Comment: Sorry, I forget to tell about that part. Change it to `compile project(path: ':sdk-audio-1.60.1')`

Comment: Error:(5, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments [DefaultProjectDependency{dependencyProject='project ':sdk-audio-1.60.1'', configuration='default'}] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
File:                          configurations.create("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('sdk-audio-1.60.1.aar'))
dependencies {
    compile project(path: ':sdk-audio-1.60.1')
   

}    Sorry to bug u again. Please check this

Comment: did you also add the `compile project(path: ':sdk-audio-1.60.1')` in sdk-audio-1.60.1 module? try removing it.

Comment: I thought I was suppose to add it only to sdk-audio-1.60.1 module. I removed it. Where else i am suppose to add compile project(path: ':sdk-audio-1.60.1')?

Comment: you only need to add the dependency to the module that needs the dependency. Hence the meaning of **compile** is to tell the gradle that the module need  `sdk-audio-1.60.1` to work. So, in your case, you only need to add it to your `app` module.

Comment: Congrats! Then please accept my answer to close this.

Comment: yes ..sure..i am new to this..how to do that? please tell me

Comment: There is a button on the top left of my answer. Click it as accepted answer. Btw, welcome to stackoverflow ;)